# Testing hardware random number generators?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, cryptographic-hardware, statistical-test

1. I would like to know how to test hardware random number generators.
2. What techniques, tools or tricks to solve the problem ?
3. Any practical difficulties, implementation complexities etc.

Comment: A related [answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8438/555).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How random are commercial TRNGS](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8418/how-random-are-commercial-trngs)

Comment: [**Answer**](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18088/12164) related to 1 & 2.

Answer (score 1):

NIST has a lot of information on testing random number generators at http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/index.html that might be of value to you.