# Is reverse engineering SHA256-HMAC function possible?

Tags: hmac, sha-256, brute-force-attack, hotp

Assume HMAC function is used to generate a 6-digt integers time-based onetime password. As follows:

$$K_h =\operatorname{HMAC}(k,t) = H((k\oplus\text{opad})\mathbin\| H((k\oplus\text{ipad})\mathbin\|t))$$

Then:

$$T=K_h \bmod 10^6$$
where $t$ is time, $k$ is a secret key, and $T$ is a one-time password.

Now assume that an attacker knows t and can observe unlimited number of one-time passwords. Is it possible for him to solve for the secret key ($k$)?
References would be nice.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. I've edited your question. Please check the equations. What is $T$, the password? Why don't you use Key Derivation Functions?

Comment: For an argument of security even if the full $K_h$ leaked, see Mihir Bellare: [_New Proofs for NMAC and HMAC: Security Without Collision-Resistance_](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.pdf), in [proceedings of Crypto 2006](https://doi.org/10.1007/11818175_36).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SHA256 HMAC brute force with chosen plaintext attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8087/sha256-hmac-brute-force-with-chosen-plaintext-attacks) @fgrieu I did not find something important to add your previous answer even after 5 years.

Comment: I agree with kelalaka here, this is a dupe. The change of base and shortening of the hash bits (to about 20 bits) doesn't change anything in that regard. So we have to close this question. On the bright side: you have your answer. Don't forget to vote up or comment here if anything is not clear.